# Laravel failing with error message: Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I think I've made a mistake and unfortunately now my Laravel site doesn't correctly build anymore.

I am not sure where to look for troubleshooting this issue. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```
root@f506ece6f4ea:/var/www/html# php public/index.php

Fatal error: Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Http\Kernel does not exist in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(790): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#1 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\\Http\\Kernel')
#2 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(265): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\\Http\\Kernel', Array, false)
#3 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(787): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Conta in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 790
root@f506ece6f4ea:/var/www/html# ls -al app/Http/
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 Controllers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2823 Feb 28 20:31 Kernel.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 Middleware
root@f506ece6f4ea:/var/www/html# cat composer.json
{
    "name": "dennis00/laravel-example",
    "description": "Example of Laravel Distro",
    "type": "project",
    "license": "GPL-2.0+",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "require": {
        "dennis00/laravel-distro": "dev-master@dev",
        "laravel/horizon": "^4.0@dev"
    }
}
root@f506ece6f4ea:/var/www/html# ls vendor
autoload.php  cakephp dennis00  doctrine   egulias  fideloper   jakub-onderka  laravel  monolog  nette  ocramius  paragonie  phpstan  psy        ramsey     symfony   vlucas
bin       composer  dnoegel   dragonmantank  erusev   guzzlehttp  jean85       league   nesbot   nikic  opis  phpoption  psr      ralouphie  swiftmailer  tijsverkoyen
```

Comment: Did you delete the app/Http directory?

Comment: It is saying that `App\Http\Kernel` does not exist. So if you go to `app/Http` make sure there is a `Kernel.php` file.

Comment: They do exist!  drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 Controllers
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2823 Feb 28 20:31 Kernel.php
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Feb 28 20:31 Middleware

Comment: And if you open that file, is the class name still `Kernel` (case sensitive)?

Comment: Does app/Http/Kernel.php have the namespace at the top of the file `namespace App\Http;`?

Comment: root@f506ece6f4ea:/var/www/html/app/Http# head Kernel.php <?php namespace App\Http; use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel; class Kernel extends HttpKernel -  Seems fine, but not all the vendor packages seem to be installed, it didn't install the dev-packages. Could that be related?

Comment: No, `require-dev` packages are not needed for it to run. Perhaps try removing the vendor folder, removing the composer.lock file and do a fresh `composer install`?

Comment: Have you tried `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: And also check the permissions of folder and files

Comment: Is it intended that your `autoload` section does not contain a PSR-4 entry for the `App` namespace prefix?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do the following

1. Check your psr-4 in composer.json. It should have

   > "autoload": {
   >       "psr-4": {
   >           "App\": "app/"
   >       } }
2. Delete `vendor` directory
3. run `composer update`